# Extracting XML values in multidimensional array c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, multidimensional-array

I have an xml file as below, and I need to extract values and put them inside a multidimensional array. The idea is, when I have more than one tag `<string>` per root element `<Etiquette>`, I need to repeat the same other values with each different value of the tag `<string>`

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <ArrayOfEtiquette xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Etiquette>
     <BgColor>#8075D1C5</BgColor>
     <BorderColor>#FF4E5B6F</BorderColor>
     <AssociatedAffaireId>
       <string>d4689f33-5600-47fe-883d-efcbf5e469c2</string>
       <string>1bae35dd-d501-4d87-bdd4-147fc0ba29d2</string>
     </AssociatedAffaireId>
     <Label>Ouverte</Label>
    </Etiquette>
    <Etiquette>
     <BgColor>#80949CA8</BgColor>
     <BorderColor>#FF155E70</BorderColor>
     <AssociatedAffaireId>
       <string>203cc4a8-8c24-4a2d-837c-29c7c1f73007</string>
     </AssociatedAffaireId>
     <Label>Fermée</Label>
    </Etiquette>
   </ArrayOfEtiquette>
```

Desired result:

```
{"#8075D1C5","#FF4E5B6F","d4689f33-5600-47fe-883d-efcbf5e469c2","Ouverte"}
{"#8075D1C5","#FF4E5B6F","1bae35dd-d501-4d87-bdd4-147fc0ba29d2","Ouverte"}
{"#80949CA8","#FF155E70","203cc4a8-8c24-4a2d-837c-29c7c1f73007","Fermée"}
```

Regards,

Comment: What have you tried to solve the solution on your own? Please have a look at [XDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `XDocument`

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile7.xml");
var mdAarray = xdoc.Descendants("Etiquette")
                   .SelectMany(etiquette => 
                               etiquette.Descendants("string")
                                        .Select(associatedaffaire => new string[] {
                                          etiquette.Element("BgColor").Value.ToString(),
                                          etiquette.Element("BorderColor").Value.ToString(),
                                          associatedaffaire.Value.ToString(),
                                          etiquette.Element("Label").Value.ToString() }))
                    .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mdAarray));
```

OUTPUT

```
[
 ["#8075D1C5","#FF4E5B6F","d4689f33-5600-47fe-883d-efcbf5e469c2","Ouverte"],
 ["#8075D1C5","#FF4E5B6F","1bae35dd-d501-4d87-bdd4-147fc0ba29d2","Ouverte"],
 ["#80949CA8","#FF155E70","203cc4a8-8c24-4a2d-837c-29c7c1f73007","Fermée"]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication157
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            var results = doc.Descendants("Etiquette")
                .SelectMany(x => x.Descendants("string")
                    .Select(y => new { BgColor = (string)x.Element("BgColor"), BorderColor = (string)x.Element("BorderColor"), UID = (string)y }))
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

I you want just an array instead of anonymous type use :

```
new string[] { (string)x.Element("BgColor"), (string)x.Element("BorderColor"), (string)y }
```

Answer (score 0):

you only need to iterate first on `Etiquette` then iterate again on `AssociatedAffaireId`

Each time you can insert inside the array or list (I will use list for simplicity)

```
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("pathToXml.xml");
    // iterate all Etiquette elements
    foreach (var etiquette in xdoc.Root.Elements("Etiquette"))
    {
        // store common values
        string bgColor = etiquette.Element("BgColor").Value;
        string borderColor = etiquette.Element("BorderColor").Value;
        string label = etiquette.Element("Label").Value;
        // iterate all AssociatedAffaireId.string elements and add to list
        var associatedAffaireIdEl = etiquette.Element("AssociatedAffaireId");
        foreach (var associatedAffaireId in associatedAffaireIdEl.Elements("string"))
        {
            string aaid = associatedAffaireId.Value;
            listOfArray.Add(new string[]{bgColor, borderColor, aaid, label});
        }
    }
```

I hope this could help.

Sorry I found some errors. Check out my fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ouhG20).